# What is the C# equivalent of Java unsigned right shift operator >>>

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert some Java code to C#. How can the following [unsigned right shift operation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) be represented in C#?

```
int src1, src2, ans;
ans = src1 >>> src2;
```

Answer (score 26):

You have to cast first, there is not one operator for >>>, code sample:

```
 int x = -100;
 int y = (int)((uint)x >> 2);
 Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Comment: hi Peer, can u tell me equivalent expression of  `(hash >>> 0)` in C#?

Comment: If the type of your hash is an int. It is the same.

Answer (score 9):

C#'s `>>` operator is sensitive to the operator's signed status (`int` vs `uint`). If you need to operate on an `int`, cast to `uint` first.

Answer (score 6):

The `>>>` syntax in Java is for unsigned right shifts, which is necessary as a concept because Java *doesn't have a specific data type for unsigned integers*.

However, C# does; in C#, you would just use `>>` with an *unsigned type* - so any of `ulong`, `uint`, `ushort`, `byte` - and it will perform the expected "fill the MSB with zero" behavior, because that is what `>>` *does* on unsigned integers, even if the input MSB is set.

If you don't want to change the code to use unsigned types throughout, you can probably use an extension method:

```cs
public static int UnsignedRightShift(this int signed, int places)
{
    unchecked // just in case of unusual compiler switches; this is the default
    {
        var unsigned = (uint)signed;
        unsigned >>= places;
        return (int)unsigned;
    }
}
public static long UnsignedRightShift(this long signed, int places)
{
    unchecked // just in case of unusual compiler switches; this is the default
    {
        var unsigned = (ulong)signed;
        unsigned >>= places;
        return (long)unsigned;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for explaining *why* Java has / needs this operator and why C# doesn't. The rest of this comment is a detailed constructive narrative on the >> vs >>> operator as mandated by the little clipboard merchant that objected to my succinct initial comment.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's just [>>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691377%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) whether it is signed or not depends on whether it is an int/long or uint/ulong, so you would have to cast as necessary

Answer (score 3):

you can use this method instead operator `>>>`.

```
int src1, src2, ans;
ans = rightMove(src1 , src2);

        int rightMove(int value, int pos)
        {
            if (pos != 0)
            {
                int mask = 0x7fffffff;
                value >>= 1;
                value &= mask;
                value >>= pos - 1;
            }
            return value;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting from C# 11, there is a native `>>>` operator. See [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#unsigned-right-shift-operator-)