# C# bitwise operator vs Javascript bitwise operator

Tags: javascript, c#, bitwise-operators

I am not familiar with bitwise operator. I have these code:

```
var value= -2145643504;
value = (value << 1) | (value >> 27);
//result: -16
```

Both C# and JavaScript result the same *-16* But in JavaScript there is another operator *>>>* which C# has not. Code in JavaScript:

```
 var value= -2145643504;
 value = (value << 1) | (value >>> 27);
 //result: 3680304    //wanted result in C#
```

Any solutions to get it in C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the C# equivalent of Java unsigned right shift operator >>>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125127/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-java-unsigned-right-shift-operator) Although this is specifically for Java this is the same for JavaScript

Comment: Try: `value = (value << 1) | (int)((uint)value >> 27);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript you are doing a [Unsigned right shift assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift_assignment) with `>>>`.

---

[To duplicate this in C# you will need to use `>>` but you must first cast the int.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125127/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-java-unsigned-right-shift-operator)

```
int x = -100;
int y = (int)((uint)x >> 2);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Comment: I'm converting kindof hashing mechanism from JavaScript to C# with zero experience of C# and this helped me so damn much! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
            var value = -2145643504;
            value = (value << 1) | rightMove(value , 27);
            //value = 3680304

        int rightMove(int value, int pos)
        {
            if (pos != 0)
            {
                int mask = 0x7fffffff;
                value >>= 1;
                value &= mask;
                value >>= pos - 1;
            }
            return value;
        }
```