# What is >>>= from Java in C#

Tags: java, c#

I am currently converting a Java Program. And I come by the byte shift operator.

I'd like to know what the `>>>=` operator means in C#. Is it just `>>=` ?
Does `>>=` shift the sign in C#?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html `The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position, while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension.`

Comment: `>>>=` isn't valid C#.

Comment: `>>` is different than `>>>`. They are the same for positive numbers, but for negative numbers they're not. `>>>` changes the MSB to 0. AFAIK, `>>>` doesn't exist in C#, so you'll have to implement it by first setting the MSB to 0, then using `>>`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125127/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-java-unsigned-right-shift-operator

Comment: @Youssef13 setting the MSB to zero will change the result, though, since the MSB is almost always going to be preserved in a right-shift; the "real answer" is: use unsigned types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `>>>` syntax in Java is for unsigned right shifts, which is necessary as a concept because Java *doesn't have a specific data type for unsigned integers*.

However, C# does; in C#, you would just use `>>` with an *unsigned type* - so any of `ulong`, `uint`, `ushort`, `byte` - and it will perform the expected "fill the MSB with zero" behavior, because that is what `>>` *does* on unsigned integers, even if the input MSB is set.

If you don't want to change the code to use unsigned types throughout, you can probably use an extension method:

```cs
public static int UnsignedRightShift(this int signed, int places)
{
    unchecked // just in case of unusual compiler switches; this is the default
    {
        var unsigned = (uint)signed;
        unsigned >>= places;
        return (int)unsigned;
    }
}
public static long UnsignedRightShift(this long signed, int places)
{
    unchecked // just in case of unusual compiler switches; this is the default
    {
        var unsigned = (ulong)signed;
        unsigned >>= places;
        return (long)unsigned;
    }
}
```

I've written this long-hand for readability, but the compiler optimizes this pretty well - for example for the `int` version:

```cs
.maxstack 8

ldarg.0
ldarg.1
ldc.i4.s 31
and
shr.un
ret
```

(the only difference in the `long` version is that it masks with `63` instead of `31`)

They can be written more tersely as:

```cs
public static int UnsignedRightShift(this int signed, int places)
    => unchecked((int)((uint)signed >> places));
public static long UnsignedRightShift(this long signed, int places)
    => unchecked((long)((ulong)signed >> places));
```